# producing a 2 class label prediction with neuralnet package in R

Tags: r, neural-network

I am working with the neuralnet package in R (I am more familiar with nnet).

My target variable is a 2 label class. (Phone_Sales 1/0). I have a train and test set. Also, all variable were normalized to [0,1] scale.

My nn model is:

```
wireless_model <- neuralnet(formula = Phone_sale ~ Topflight + Balance +
                              Qual_miles + cc1_miles. + cc2_miles. + 
                              cc3_miles. + Bonus_miles + Bonus_trans +
                              Flight_miles_12mo + Flight_trans_12 +
                              Online_12 + Email + Club_member + Any_cc_miles_12mo,
                            data = wireless_train, hidden=1, linear.output=FALSE)
```

the predicted results from `wireless_model$net.result` are produced as floats between 0 and 1 (in fact almost all hover very close to zero). ie .07 and .21, etc instead of 1 or 0.

So obviously when I compare my train to my test- my prediction is bad b/c of the two different types of DV.

I want the predicted results to be in the form of either 1 or 0. I am sure I did not use specify a correct setting somewhere in the neuralnet package.

A guess is that I may need to set the "family" in the formula for logistic so I get on 1 or 0 output. But not sure how that works in this package.

Any help?

Comment: There are quite a few unanswered question with tags: [r] [neural-net] because posters do not put their test data in their questions

Comment: You should provide some portion of your data for this problem to be reproducible and for others to help you. Second thing is that, neural network does not give output in the form of 1 or 0 since the activation functions used in neural networks are not step functions but instead they are generally `sigmoid` or `tanh` (smooth curves going from 0 to 1). You can always round-off your results to obtain 0 or 1. @IShouldBuyABoat even questions with reproducible code and data that has tags `[r]` `[neural-net]` are mostly unanswered, may be due to low patronising of neural networks.